# groovy eclipse and scripts that aren't classes

Tags: eclipse, groovy

The groovy eclipse tutorial launches off in the direction of making a class.

If I just want to make a script, what do I do? Just make a file in some folder that is named 'something.groovy' and expect eclipse to be willing to run it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the new Groovy Class Wizard, there is a checkbox to create a script instead of a class:

[image: Check this box to create a script]

Alternatively, you can create a regular class and delete all the contents except for the package statement.  That is a script.

A couple of points, though.  The script should be in a source folder with a proper package statement if not in the default package.  If not, you will not have any editing support for your script.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the `groovy` plugin for `eclipse` but there should be no problem creating a simple groovy script and running it from Command line or from `Eclipse`.

Save the following as `hello.groovy` somewhere:

```
System.out.println("Hello Groovy");
```

Create a **Java** run configuration it with the `groovy` jar in the classpath and main method is in `groovy.lang.GroovyShell`. Pass the script name as an argument (You can use `${resource_loc}`) to make it a generic run configuration and it will work fine.

**Edit:** You can also find instructions on running groovy scripts on the [Groovy website](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Running)

Comment: RonK is correct but I would recommend making the script more groovy with content like:   println "Hello Groovy"

Comment: Thanks - I'm not yet groovy myself to be used to this syntax :)